# Correct schema for an Entity Reference in config settings

Tags: entities, 9, configuration

#### Background

I am creating a schema for a custom module's config settings, which are saved from a simple settings form. It has some basic fields, such as a checkbox for a Boolean value for hiding some data. However, it also has an entity reference field (e.g. `hide_data_terms`) that allows selecting taxonomy terms from a specific bundle `data_terms`. It will save the term IDs to the settings YAML.

Here's my attempt at a **my_module.schema.yml** so far:

```yaml
my_module.settings:
  type: mapping
  label: Settings
  mapping:
    hide_data:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Hide Data'
    hide_data_terms:
      type: entity_reference_selection.default:taxonomy_term
      label: 'Hide Data for Terms'
```

#### Problem

I'm not sure if `entity_reference_selection.default:taxonomy_term` is correct. Also, I have three terms saved from the settings page, and when using [Config Inspector](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_inspector), it shows errors like this:

```
Name              | Label     | Type      | Value | Error
------------------------------------------------------------------
hide_data_terms.0 | Undefined | undefined | 1234  | missing schema
hide_data_terms.1 | Undefined | undefined | 2034  | missing schema
hide_data_terms.2 | Undefined | undefined | 3287  | missing schema
```

**my_module.settings.yml** looks like this, with `hide_data_terms` containing an array of taxonomy term IDs:

```yaml
hide_data: false
hide_data_terms:
  - 1234
  - 2034
  - 3287
```

What's wrong with the schema, if anything, or what should it be? I can't create a schema for each array element, because there can be any number of terms selected, or none of them.

#### Another Question:

The settings YAML does not have a "default config hash" for some reason. Most config YAMLs have it. Is that needed, and why isn't that in there?

Edit: I found the answer to the default config hash question. That is only used when the config is added on module install. See ConfigInstaller.php and search for `default_config_hash`.

Comment: I think you'll need to use "sequence" to define that field. It allows for multiple unknown values. Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata#sequence-definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `entity_reference_selection.default:taxonomy_term` type is incorrect as this config is used for field settings in the Entity reference type fields.

It is defined in the `core/config/schema/core.data_types.schema.yml` as `entity_reference_selection.default:*`.

So if you replace this type in your configuration with its definition it would look like this:

```
my_module.settings:
  type: mapping
  label: Settings
  mapping:
    hide_data:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Hide Data'
    hide_data_terms:
      type: mapping
      label: 'Hide Data for Terms'
      mapping:
        target_type:
          type: string
          label: 'Type of item to reference'
        target_bundles:
          type: sequence
          label: 'types'
          nullable: true
          sequence:
            type: string
            label: 'Bundle'
        sort:
          type: mapping
          label: 'Sort settings'
          mapping:
            field:
              type: string
              label: 'Sort by'
            direction:
              type: string
              label: 'Sort direction'
        auto_create:
          type: boolean
          label: 'Create referenced entities if they don''t already exist'
        auto_create_bundle:
          type: string
          label: 'Bundle assigned to the auto-created entities.'
```

Which is why you are getting the missing schema error.

As pointed out by @unusedspoon in the comment, you should use the sequence type for specifying an array of values.

The correct schema would look like this:

```yaml
my_module.settings:
  type: mapping
  label: Settings
  mapping:
    hide_data:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Hide Data'
    hide_data_terms:
      type: sequence
      label: 'Hide Data for Terms'
      sequence:
        type: integer
        label: 'Term ID'
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you.